# Why, replacing DelegateCommand with Command is not working in Prism

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

In Prism Mvvm, **`Prism.Unity`** library, when I replace `DelegateCommand` with Binding Mvvm `Command`. It is not working. This is my working code

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private DelegateCommand _navigationCommand;

    private INavigationService _navigationService;
    public DelegateCommand NavigateCommand => _navigationCommand ?? (_navigationCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCommand));

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
    void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SecondPage");
    }
}
```

Now I make changes in `DeletegateCommand`, `Command` not getting fire. This is my modified code

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ICommand _navigationCommand { private set; get; }
    private INavigationService _navigationService;

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _navigationCommand = new Command(() => ExecuteCommand());
    }
    void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SecondPage");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Prism.Forms it is best framework for MVVM

Comment: Can you point us to the `Command` implementation? Side note: why do you want to not use `DelegateCommand`?

Comment: @Haukinger - Thank you for your input. I had wrong command implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement command wrong in XAML due to that I was facing this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not completely sure that this could be the reason but I think your code should look something like this:

```
public ICommand NavigationCommand { set; get; }
```

Then set it in the constructor:

```
 public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
 {
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    NavigationCommand = new Command(ExecuteCommand);
 }
```

And your method would look something like below:

```
private void ExecuteCommand(object obj) 
{
    _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SecondPage");
}
```

use `object obj` if you want to pass any data as Command Parameter

Comment: @Haukinger Make it private it doesn't matter, but there are scenarios where people want to access it publicly! I anyways never said that it should not be private now did I?

Comment: name one that is not a violation of separation of concerns or feature envy

Comment: @Haukinger I actually agree with you on this but don't you think in that case removing the `set` part all together would be the best solution in that way there won't be a violation there